# Using Power Query to pull data from daily reports to put into a comprehensive table

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a daily report that I run every morning. This report is very basic and looks something like this

```
|Sales Amount for 19 Mar 2024   |
|-------------------------------|
|Sales Dept Sales  |      22,000|
|Sales Dept Costs  |      -7,000|
|Service Dept Sales|      11,500|
|Service Dept Costs|      -5,550|
|-------------------------------|
```

It's more detailed than that, but thats a simpified example.

I have another spreadsheet that keeps track of these amounts throughout the month (Monthly Report), and uses the values they provide to run some calculations. What I would like to do is get this setup so that when I download the Daily Report the values will fill in the correct cells in the Monthly Report based on the day the Daily Report is run (for example if today is 3/19 but I want to run the report for friday 3/15)

My Monthly Report looks something like this

```
|----------------Sales Dept---------------|
|Day|----Sales---|---Cost---|----Profit---|
| 18|      11,500|    -8,200|        3,300|
| 19|      22,000|    -7,000|       15,000|
| 20|
|--------------Service Dept---------------|
|Day|----Sales---|---Cost---|----Profit---|
| 18|      15,500|    -5,200|       10,300|
| 19|      11,500|    -5,500|        5,950|
| 20|
```

Each department has rows for each day of the month. If I run the report for a day that already has values placed in the Monthly Report it should overwrite those values, and if I run the report on a day that is blank those values should be filled in.

I am currently using power query to clean up the Daily Report but I'm stumped on how to get it to pull the data and match up the date.

Would this be easier to accomplish if the different departments were in their own columns instead of in rows beneath each other? Any suggestions on how to implement this would be appreciated.

Comment: If the goal of the report is to provide cohesive visual information, then row grouping by department would make it easier to print and read. If the data is going to be consumed and possibly further manipulated, then going with column groups would provide better functionality.